# QGIS crashes when using heatmap plugin

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-2

I am using QGIS 2.14.1 in Ubuntu 15.04 and when i click Raster -> HeatMap -> HeatMap. My QGIS crashes and closes automatically even there is a point layer loaded in the canvas(HeatMap Plugin expects a point layer). Any solutions for the same?

Answer (score 1):

This is not happening on OSX, but I am using 2.14.2. Try upgrading to 2.14.2. It should be available for Ubuntu.